# Understanding natural $R$-Algebra structure on some abelian groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

**Definition** *($R$-Algebra)*: Let $R$ be a commutative ring with a ring homomorphism $\phi : R\to S$ such that $\phi(R)\subseteq Center(S)$, then the ring $S$ is a $R$-Algebra

**Base Question:**
$R$ is a commutative ring. And let $M$ be an $R$-Module. Now I want to show that $End_{R\text{-Mod}}(M)$ is an $R$-Algebra.

To show it is indeed an $R$-algebra, I usually want to give explicit ring morphism satisfying above definition.

As it is said: I can give the answer as below:

We can prove that $End_{R\text{-Mod}}(M)$ is a ring with $+$ and composition.
And we can define,
$$\begin{align*}
\psi:R&\to End_{R\text{-Mod}}(M)\\ 
r&\mapsto \left(\lambda_r: m\mapsto rm\right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

And we can show it is a ring morphism and its image indeed inside the center.

**My question:** However, contrary to the above approach, people are showing some ring to be a $R$-Algebra they use $R$-Module structure and some compatible conditions. But why? Any $R$-Algebra is a $R$-Module but not vice versa in general.

So to clarify this, can we give practical equivalent definition of $R$-Algebra?

Comment: Can you give an example of where "they use $R$-module structure and some compatible condition"? This sounds like exactly the approach you've sketched to prove that End$_R(M)$ is an $R$-algebra.

Comment: I think my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275948/show-the-ring-is-a-division-algebra/4276055#4276055) could be helpful.